# My keyboard does not work in Tails 1.1.1, what could be causing it?

Tags: tails

Keyboard does not work at all in Iceweasel, and in gpedit backspace and P keys do not work. Oddly enough, P seems to refresh the screen. What could be the issue? Tails is running off of a USB stick on a Lenovo Y580 laptop.